# How to find row index for dynamic table and on basis of that get column text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the table rows created dynamically. I want to find the first column text on click of row. How to find row index for dynamic table and on basis of that get column text?

```
// table row
if (tableType == "campaignData") {
    var newCampaignRow = `
        <tr aria-selected="false" class="campaign-table-row slds-hint-parent">
        <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">CMP` + resultRowsJson[i]["Campaign_CD"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Campaign_NM"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Send_Type"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Status"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Sends"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + formatDateCreated + `</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    `;
    $("#campaign_rows").append(newCampaignRow);


    // click function for row and get the row index and column text.
    $("#tbl").click("tr", function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        console.log("Row index is: " + index);
        var myValue = $('#tbl tr').eq(index).find("div[id=code]").html();
        console.log(myValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `.find("div[id=code]")` supposed to select? Selecting by ID is usually done with **#id**. And i cant see any div in your code with the id "code"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to solving your problem;

```js
var resultRowsJson = [
  { "Campaign_CD":1,"Campaign_NM":"Sample","Send_Type":"e-mail", "Status":"booked","Sends":"none"}
];

var globalRowCounter = 0;
var formatDateCreated = "temp variable will change after problem solved";

function AddNew(){
   var i = 0; // I think you forgot this variable, guess codes from in a loop :)
    var newCampaignRow = `
        <tr aria-selected="false"
            onclick="rowClick(this)"
            class="campaign-table-row slds-hint-parent"
            data-row-index="`+globalRowCounter+`">
        <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;">
          <div id="code" class="slds-truncate" title="">
              CMP` + resultRowsJson[i]["Campaign_CD"] + `
           </div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Campaign_NM"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Send_Type"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Status"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + resultRowsJson[i]["Sends"] + `</div>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="">` + formatDateCreated + `</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    `;
    $("#campaign_rows").append(newCampaignRow);
    globalRowCounter++;
}



// click function for row and get the row index and column text.
function rowClick(ths)  {
    var index = $(ths).attr("data-row-index");
    console.log("Row index is: " + index);
    var myValue = $('#campaign_rows tr').eq(index).find("div[id='code']").html();
    console.log(myValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="campaign_rows" class="table table-bordered">
<table>

<button type="button" onclick="AddNew()">Add new tr</button>
```